# Bitbucket pipelines artifact is not present in the next step?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

Here is my  bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    feature/*:
      - step:
          name: test artifacts
          script:
            - mkdir abc
            - echo "abc1" > abc/testartifacts.txt
          artifacts:
            - abc
      - step:
          script:
            - ls -altrh
            - cat abc/*
```

In the second step `abc/` is not present... Why? What am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If needing a whole directory stored you need to use `dir/**` syntax...

```
     artifacts:
        - abc/**
```

**Limitations:**

**THIS WILL NOT STORE EMPTY DIRECTORIES...**

This would ideally initially produced an error or warning then if `dir` is invalid.

Comment: Everything around artifacts could help some warnings https://stackoverflow.com/q/56196454/11715259